# Is the buckets of water problem in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np, open-problem

Continuing from this question: [the buckets of water problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30357/the-buckets-of-water-problem).

(All the definitions can be found there, so I will not repeat them).

As seen there by Yuval's answer, the problem is NP-Hard.
I was attempting to prove its NP-completeness, and while doing so - I was suddenly not sure whether or not it belongs to NP.

Because the witness is most likely to be a series of actions (filling buckets etc ...), and that might be too long.

Of course, we can change the definition of the language, in such a way we will limit the number of actions to be polynomial or make it part of the input (with a slight adjustment to represent the number of actions in unary, so it won't be log of the number's value).

But, I find it interesting to ask if this is a must?

And if we do not change anything - Can we tell for sure it is not NP? That there is no better (polynomial) witness.

Comment: If we one bucket of capacity 1, and one of capacity $C \geq m$, then we can get the number $m$, but doing so will take $2m$ steps. So if the input $m$ is coded in binary, then we can't use the full action sequence as a certificate. Of course, there could be ways to express it in a more concise way.

Comment: One more observation: if all buckets are originally empty, then the problem can be solved in polynomial (with respect to input length in binary) time. Indeed, in this case, in any moment, the quantities of water in each bucket are integer linear combinations of bucket capacities. On the other hand, there is an explicit construction that can reach any prescribed positive linear combination that fits in the largest bucket.

Comment: Indeed, if bucket capacities are $c_1 \leqslant c_2 \leqslant \ldots \leqslant c_n$ and we want to have exactly $m$ of water in some bucket, it is enough for us to get $m \bmod c_1$ water in the smallest bucket. Because $m$ is represented linearly in terms of $c_i$, we can get $m \bmod c_1$ by repeatedly applying the following construction.

Comment: Suppose that all buckets, except for the smallest (first), are empty and there is $0 \leqslant y < c_1$ water in the first bucket. We will achieve the same situation, but with $(y + c_i) \bmod c_1$ instead of $y$. To do so, fill the $i$-th bucket, move the water from $i$-th bucket to the first till the first bucket is full and empty the first bucket. Now, there is $c_i - (c_1 - y) = c_i + y - c_1$ water in the $i$-th bucket. We can repeatedly drain $c_1$ water from the $i$-th bucket till there is only $(c_i + y) \mod c_1$ water left and move all this water to the first bucket.

Comment: Hence, we just need to check whether m is divisible by $\gcd(c_1,c_2, \ldots, c_n)$. This is a pretty classical result, I just wanted to highlight that the main difficulty of the problem lies exactly in the original water quantities. For example, any time we fill any of the buckets, part of the information about the original state is irrecoverably lost, hence looking for witnesses that keep track of "how far the original state still affects the current" seems to be a promising approach.

Comment: I proved that the problem for non-empty buckets is in NP along the same lines, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is in NP, because it is "exactly as hard" as SUBSET-SUM problem. Moreover, it *is*, in some sense, the SUBSET-SUM problem in disguise! Let's show that.

Denote the number of buckets by $n$, their capacities by $c_1 \leqslant c_2 \leqslant \ldots \leqslant c_n$ and the original quantities of water in them by $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ (here I assume without loss of generality that the buckets are sorted by their capacities). I claim that the following statements are equivalent:

1. There exists a way to get exactly $m \in [0, c_n]$ water in some bucket.
2. There exists a subset $S$ of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, such that $\sum\limits_{i \in S} a_i \equiv m \pmod{\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)}$.

To prove the $1 \Rightarrow 2$ implication, let's notice that, at every moment of time, the quantity of water in each bucket can be expressed as "sum of $a_i$ over some subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$" $+$ "some integer linear combination of $c_i$, with negative coefficients allowed". Indeed, we can check that all three allowed operations preserve this property. The latter part is divisible by $\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$, hence $m$ being possible to obtain implies the condition $2$.

The $2 \Rightarrow 1$ implication follows from the same type of the argument as I presented in the comments. I will reproduce it here for completeness. Indeed, suppose that $m \equiv \sum\limits_{i \in S} a_i \pmod{\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)}$. Because $\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$ is representable as a linear combination of $c_i$, we can represent $m$ as an integer linear combination of $c_i$ and $a_i$, with all coefficients before $a_i$ being $0$ or $1$.

Clearly, it is enough to obtain $m \bmod c_1$ water somehow (after doing that, we can just repeatedly add $c_1$ of water). But, as long as we are interested in obtaining something only *modulo $c_1$*, we can replace all negative coefficients before $c_i$ in this sum with nonnegative ones (by adding $c_1$ appropriate number of times). Hence, we have a representation $m \equiv \sum\limits_{i \in S} a_i + \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n k_i c_i \pmod{c_1}$, where $k_i$ are some nonnegative integers.

Now, suppose that we have $x$ water in the $i$-th bucket and $y$ water in the first bucket. Then, we can get $(x + y) \bmod c_1$ water in the first bucket and make the $i$-th bucket empty. Indeed, try to move all the water from $i$-th bucket to the first. If $x + y < c_1$, then we are done. Otherwise, the first bucket is full now and the $i$-th bucket contains $x + y - c_1$ water. Empty the first bucket and repeatedly drain $c_1$ of water from the $i$-th bucket, until there is only $(x + y) \bmod c_1$ water left. Then move all the water to the first bucket.

By doing the operation from the previous paragraph for all $i$ in $S$, we can get $\left( \sum\limits_{i \in S} a_i \right) \bmod c_1$ water in the first bucket (if $1$ is not in S, we need to empty the first bucket beforehand). Now, for each $i$ from $2$ to $n$, repeat the same operation $k_i$ times, but now fill the $i$-th bucket before the operation. In the end, the first bucket will contain exactly $\left( \sum\limits_{i \in S} a_i + \sum\limits_{i=2}^n k_i c_i \right) \bmod c_1 = m \bmod c_1$ water.

Hence, this problem is equivalent to some kind of "modular subset sum", with modulo being equal to $\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)$. As for NP witness, any witness for "modular subset sum" problem will do, for example the set $S$.

A more natural witness in the context of the original problem is a "compressed sequence of operations", in the sense that we allow commands of the type "repeat a given sequence of operations a given number of times". The proof above can be translated into such a witness, and a particularly simple one (no nested block commands, we repeat only some fixed short blocks, et cetera). I am not 100% sure whether it is possible to simulate a general compressed sequence of operations in polynomial time, but I am inclined to believe that the answer is "yes, it is possible". However, it is definitely possible to simulate *sequences arising from the above proof* quickly, though requiring that makes the witness much less natural.

Indeed, the second part of the proof constructs a sequence of operations of polynomial length, but with a catch that the following two "mega-operations" are also allowed:

1. Given a bucket with $x$ water, repeatedly drain it by $c_1$, till there is only $x \bmod c_1$ water left. The first (the smallest) bucket should be empty before this operation. This operation is used repeatedly thorough the proof
2. If we have $m \mod c_1$ water in the first bucket, empty the largest bucket, move $m \mod c_1$ water into it and repeatedly add $c_1$ water until there is $m$ water in the largest bucket. Used only once in the end.

These "mega-operations" correspond to some simple arithmetical operations on the quantities of waters in the buckets and $c_i$'s, hence they can be carried quickly in *the model of computation we are using*, despite the fact that they take very large number of *elementary operations with buckets*.

Comment: Nice write-up. Can you clarify what is considered a solution to the bucket of water problem, how it should be encoded and how an encoded solution will be verified according to the definition of NP? They are parts of the question, as indicated by [Aron's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127952/is-the-buckets-of-water-problem-in-np#comment268207_127952).

Comment: Do you mean specifically the "compressed sequence of operations" witness I talk about in the last paragraph? As I said, technically speaking, the set $S$ of indices, such that $\sum_{i \in S} a_i \equiv m \pmod{\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n)}$ is a witness for the bucket of water problem (and verifying it takes only computing some gcd's and remainders modulo for input numbers, hence takes polynomial time). The set $S$ is a NP-witness for the original problem, though, it is not obvious that it is a witness.

Comment: By "compressed sequence of operations", I mean something like this: either one of basic commands, or concatenation of two compressed sequences, or "repeat some compression sequence $r$ times, $r$ is given in binary". It is still not obvious that this is a NP witness for the original problem. A priori, it could be the case that the optimal sequence of operations (that can have exponential length) is "uncompressible" (can't be represented by a compressed sequence of polynomial length).  Of course, the above proof rules out such a possibility, but I don't know a simpler proof.

Comment: There is another can of worms: it is not clear whether _every_ compressed sequence of operations can be simulated in polynomial time (by "simulating" I mean obtaining the final state given the starting state and the sequence). The sequences that _arise from the above proof_ can be simulated, I will add a simple description of such sequences to my answer. But it is still not obvious that it is enough to look only for the sequences of this form. Hence, I don't consider this to be a "natural" witness, because it is still not obvious that this is actually a witness, as it usual with NP problems.